# Как вывести избранные строки файла?

Tags: linux

Вывести все строки файла ~/mytxt, в которых встречается следующая последовательность символов: любой символ, кроме A и D; 50 пробелов подряд; дата в формате xx.xx.xxxx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
grep  '[^AD];[[:space:]]\{50\};[[:digit:]]\{2\}\.[[:digit:]]\{2\}\.[[:digit:]]\{4\}' ~/mytxt
```

Comment: только, наверно все же [[:space:]]\{50,50\}; вместо [[:space:]]\{3,3\};

Comment: Да-да, я поправился.. я просто тестил на строке с тремя пробелмами.. не отсчитывать же 50 пробелов подряд :)

Comment: нет конечно, написать скрипт который будет записывать 50 пробелов в файл =)

Comment: Я ждал, когда же кто-нибудь напишет мне про это :)